# how to remove unwanted databases in xampp

Tags: xampp, wamp

First of all thanks for all the previous support and advice.

This may sound like a silly question, but in Xampp, is it possible to remove unwanted databases in Xampp, and if so how would you do it?

If not, is that feature available in Wamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up a mysql prompt.

e.g. `mysql -u username -p`

the drop the database using: 
`drop database name_of_database`

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/drop-database.html for syntax

If you mean can you do it using the interface, I believe you can do it using phpmyadmin.